# How to Query a repeated property with a list object in google appengine ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, djangoappengine

I need to construct a logical query with a repeated property and can't get it to work. 
I have a list object with topics.

```
topics = [u'string1', u'string2', ...]
```

I have a query object:

```
videos = Video.query()
videos.count()
=> 19
```

topics is a repeated string property

```
class Video
  topics = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

I want to return videos that have a topic `string1` OR `string2`. I also don't know the length of the list object before or I could just construct the query the long way with logical operators.

I tried doing this like the documentation suggests

```
videos.filter( Video.topics.IN([topics]) )
```

but that throws the error that IN expected a string not a list object.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `topics` is already a list. So you need to pass it without another list around it:

```
videos.filter( Video.topics.IN(topics) )
```

Answer (score 1):

For an arry of topics, you can use:

```
Video.query(Video.topics.IN(topics))
```

Or for a single string:

```
Video.query(Video.topics == topic)
```

source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries