# GAE NDB String list property

Tags: google-app-engine

NDB has list properties that are defined as follows
`myProp = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)`

Now say we have this as data

`myProp = ["a", "b", "c"]` and i would like to search against `myProp` with an array.  Say something like `mySearchVal = ["a", "c"]`.

I am having troubles finding how to do this. i Cannot simply do

```
MyModel.query(myProp = mySearchVal)
```

for i get the error of `Expect String, but got [u'a', u'b']`.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this.  I really do not want to do it programmatically and was hoping it was doable through ndb.  But if i must i must!

---

Edit:
Just as POW: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties does not provide the correct answer to the problem.  It simply states that 'a', 'b', or 'c' will satisify the answer.  But i want to do 'a' *and* 'c'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Query a repeated property with a list object in google appengine ndb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291341/how-to-query-a-repeated-property-with-a-list-object-in-google-appengine-ndb)

Comment: Found above ^.  I looked a bit, i am surprised i found it now and not during searchings.

Answer (score 0):

How about (are you using ndb?):

```
MyModel.query().filter(MyModel.myProp == 'a').filter(MyModel.myProp == 'b')
```

In this case, == looks for the element being in the list.

Comment: I eventually found a duplicate question somewhere on the internets of stackoverflow.  But your answer is valid, but not what i want to see.  Since 'a', 'b', 'c', there could be a lot and i do not want to use a for loop for functionality that already exists!

Comment: With ndb you would use the `AND` operator 

`MyModel.query(ndb.AND(MyModel.myProp == 'a', MyModel.myProp == 'b'))`